# How to find radix in an equation?

Tags: number-theory

How do you find radixes of the number systems used in the following equations:-

$(135)+(144)=(323)$

$\dfrac{312}{20}=13.1$

Comment: For the first one I would look at the last digits.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any general way, but in these cases it's fairly easy to guess the radix by looking at single digit calculations.

For the first one you just have to look at the last digits, which shows you that (calling the radix $r$) $4+5=a*r+3$.

For the second one start by rearranging it to: $312=20*13.1$. The 0 just moves the point, so it's equivalent to $312=2*131$. Starting from the back you have $2*1=2$ (true in any base where $2$ makes sense), so we move on and see that $2*3=a*r+1$.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

I would say - a general way: Equations

$(135)_q+(144)_q=(323)_q \Rightarrow 1q^2+3q+5 + 1q^2+4q+4 = 3q^2+2q+3$

$\frac{(312)_q}{(20)_q}=(13.1)_q\Rightarrow \frac{ 3q^2 + 1q + 2 }{ 2q+0 }=1q+3 + 1q^{-1}$

solve for q.

Comment: Okay, that is a general way - and one that I did know of - but for larger numbers the equation becomes hard to solve. So in general I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @Henrik  Yes, you are right, it would be difficult.